How to group on flutter Firebase notifications and how to open them, if they are grouped while receiving them on background and foreground
In my Firebase class i have managed to receive notifications and properly handle the navigation according to notification response body. However, i find out some difficulties while receiving multiple notifications from same chat, because in my android simulator it groups such notifications and while opening, there is no log at all, but on real device it does not group it and it works well. But still it is not right if notifications are not grouped from one chat and opening doesn't work.
This is when it works fine, when i open one by one
This one is opening only main page and no log at all
Function: I used "FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen" while app is on foreground and not terminated
Used "FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()" when app is terminated and in background mode.
All these 2 functions are working well as i mentioned for clicking notification one by one, but not as if they grouped(only on simulator).
So can someone help me on how to first of all properly group notifications from same chat. Secondly, how to open such grouped notifications and manage the navigations.
Thank you
In my android simulator it groups such notifications and while opening, there is no log at all, but on real device it does not group it and it works well. But still it is not right if notifications are not grouped from one chat and opening doesn't work.
Function: I used "FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen" while app is on foreground and not terminated
Used "FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()" when app is terminated and in background mode.

Are you using local_notification package along with the firebase messaging package? If not, you can check out https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications I did grouped notification before and I have always used this package for displaying notification in my app. When displaying notification with this package, AFAIK you can use this method to get notification details -- await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails(); --

Yep, i used local_notification with firebase, but im not using it to show notifications, as it works for notifications while app in use, but not when app is terminated and in background or foreground.
Also i used await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getActiveNotifications to get list of grouped notifications inside my "FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen" function, to try testing opening group notifications while app is on foreground, but no log at all.
I will try to get flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails()

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails() it does not provide me details, can you correct me where i need to use it

To get details from the above function you need to configure your app to show notification using local_notification package. Only then you will get data

0
I have added following "" But and used Flutter local notifications package, and used firebase.onMessage function to get notifications, but it does not help.
The main goal is to achieve notification grouping on background terminated state, foreground state(not terminated). I dont need notification while in use of app, because i have socket.
